# MySQL find 4th highest salary of employee table

Tags: mysql, database

How to find nth highest salary from employee table.

I am also providing the best solution to do this sql query in very less time

Comment: Is this a job interview question? If not, please post your table schema, so we can actually help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM employee e1
WHERE 4 = (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT salary)
    FROM employee e2 
    WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary
);
```

if you want 2nd hightest salary then replace 4 with 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field_name) FROM table_name
ORDER BY field_name DESC
LIMIT 3,1
```

Comment: I changed the query

Comment: You can use 
down vote
accept
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM employee e1
WHERE 4 = (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT salary)
    FROM employee e2 
    WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary
);